# Why Addressables do not load my assets from cached bundles?

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

My game is supposed to be played offline, but it downloads new content on internet connection.

I have couple of Addressables groups with checked "Include in Build" option. So, when there is no internet, I expect `Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<T>(...)` will be successful, but it is not. I've got an error "Can not resolve destination host".

Probably, I didn't catch how "Include in Build" actually works. Is there a way to include my assets into build, and just update them with `Addressables.UpdateCatalogs()` and `Addressables.DownloadDependenciesAsync(...)` methods, when device is online, but load from cached downloaded bundles on offline?